# What is the average time to clear border control at Frankfurt Airport for a non EU passenger

Tags: air-travel, borders, statistics, fra

Are there any published statistics detailing the average wait to clear border control / customs at Frankfurt airport (FRA) for non EU travelers.

The reason I'm interested is knowing roughly how long I will need to queue will influence the flight I choose so I can make onward travel connections with the least amount of hassle.

EDIT: Here are some statistics for Heathrow Airport (LHR), which can be notoriously slow.

Comment: I don't think that such a statistic exists. Nobody asks you how long have you been waiting

Comment: To clear border control is just a matter of where you are in the queue. A few questions and done. Customs, however, depends on too many factors. Are you carrying unlisted items with you ? Are you required to get a visa to enter Frankfurt ? Are you just switching flights ? FRA is just like any other POE in USA. I am not an American and I have spent anywhere between 45 minutes to an hour and a half to clear border control and customs, on an average, based on that, I dont think it is too different in FRA.

Comment: Surely when a flight lands they can tell how long it takes for them to clear the queue at least giving the number of the longest wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, Frankfurt Airport has made a "[Transfer Guide](http://static.fraport.de/ONLINE/Flippbook/EN/index.html#/6/)".

It describes how to get from each terminal to the others, using their Skyline train, Eshuttle and walking.

In addition, it points out that if you have less than 30 minutes for your connecting flight, you may use the fast lane at the security checkpoint, giving you a bonus speed option to get  through if you're worried about passing those points.

It indicates maps further on in the guide, so if you can work out which terminal you arrive at, you can probably work out roughly how long it will take you.

Then in terms of your flight, we can look at the [rating for Frankfurt airport on Flightstats.com](http://www.flightstats.com/go/Airport/airportUserRatingsByAirport.do?airportCode=FRA): 3.6/5.

[Recent comments](http://www.flightstats.com/go/Airport/airportUserComments.do?airport=%28FRA%29+Frankfurt+am+Main+Airport) also indicate people get very frustrated with transfers here, however it's prudent to remember that happy people are less likely to comment than complainers.

They also have a [scorecard](http://www.flightstats.com/go/Airport/airportScorecard.do?airportCode=FRA) for different times of the day, airlines and so on, so you can get a rough idea of how likely your flight is to be delayed.